# Constrained generics with hierarchy in type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, types, parameters, hierarchy

I have a problem with generics in C# I hope you can help me out with.

```cs
public interface IElement { }

public interface IProvider<T> where T : IElement {
    IEnumerable<T> Provide();
}
```

So far it's pretty simple. I want the providers to return enumerables of specific elements.
A specific implementation of the interfaces is as follows:

```cs
public class MyElement : IElement { }

public class MyProvider : IProvider<MyElement> {
    public IEnumerable<MyElement> Provide() {
        [...]
    }
}
```

But the problem comes now when I want to use it. This does not compile because it cannot implicitly convert `MyProvider` into `IProvider<IElement>`:

```cs
IProvider<IElement> provider = new MyProvider();
```

I have to do a cast to `IProvider<IElement>` despite `MyProvider` is an `IProvider<MyElement>` and `MyElement` is an `IElement`. I could avoid the cast by making `MyProvider` also implement `IProvider<MyElement>`, but why does it not resolve the hierarchy in the type parameter?

**EDIT: As per Thomas's suggestion, we can make it covariant in `T`. But what if there are other methods like below where there are arguments of type `T`?**

```cs
public interface IProvider<T> where T : IElement {
    IEnumerable<T> Provide();
    void Add(T t);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *only* use the reference to `IProvider<IElement>` to access methods that have `T` in an output position, you could *segregate* the interface into two (please find better names for them, like `ISink<in T>` for the contravariant one):

```
public interface IProviderOut<out T> where T : IElement {
  IEnumerable<T> Provide();
}
public interface IProviderIn<in T> where T : IElement {
  void Add(T t);
}
```

Your class implements both:

```
public class MyProvider : IProviderOut<MyElement>, IProviderIn<MyElement> {
  public IEnumerable<MyElement> Provide() {
    ...
  }
  public void Add(MyElement t) {
    ...
  }
}
```

But now you use the covariant interface when you need to upcast:

```
IProviderOut<IElement> provider = new MyProvider();
```

Alternatively, your interface can inherit from both:

```
public interface IProvider<T> : IProviderIn<T>, IProviderOut<T> 
  where T : IElement { 
  // you can add invariant methods here...
}
```

And your class implements it:

```
public class MyProvider : IProvider<MyElement> ...
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I think I understand now the whole covariance-contravariance thing. Never heard of it before, but then again, I never implement my generics.

Answer (score 8):

> I have to do a cast to `IProvider<IElement>` despite `MyProvider` is an `IProvider<MyElement>` and `MyElement` is an `IElement`. Why does it not resolve the hierarchy in the type parameter?

This is a very frequently asked question. Consider the following equivalent problem:

```
interface IAnimal {}
class Tiger : IAnimal {}
class Giraffe : IAnimal {}
class MyList : IList<Giraffe> { ... }
...
IList<IAnimal> m = new MyList();
```

Now your question is: "I have to do a cast to `IList<IAnimal>` despite the fact that `MyList` is an `IList<Giraffe>` and `Giraffe` is an `IAnimal`. Why does this not work?"

It does not work because... suppose it did work:

```
m.Add(new Tiger());
```

m is a list of animals. You can add a tiger to a list of animals. But m is really a MyList, and a MyList can only contain giraffes! If we allowed this then *you could add a tiger into a list of giraffes*.

This must fail because `IList<T>` has an Add method that takes a T. Now, maybe your interface has no methods that takes a T. In that case, you can mark the interface as *covariant*, and the compiler will verify that the interface is truly safe for variance and allow the variance you want.

Comment: @EricLippet thanks a lot for the explanation. I understand it right and yeah, makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 7):

Since `T` only appears in output position in your `IProvider<T>` interface, you can make it covariant in `T`:

```
public interface IProvider<out T> where T : IElement {
    IEnumerable<T> Provide();
}
```

This will make this instruction legal:

```
IProvider<IElement> provider = new MyProvider();
```

This feature requires C# 4. Read [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solves this problem, but what happens when `IProvider<T>` does itself extend another interface? See edit above.

Comment: @caerolus, for C# IProvider<IElement> and IProvider<MyElement> are different types. This design decision is made on purpose, to prevent improper up-casting.
Conciser that you have IProvider<MyElement>, then up-casted it to IProvider<IElement> and downcast-ed to IProvider<MyElement2> - boom, exception.

Comment: I'm sorry but I fail to see how this relates. Yes, they're different types and I can't downcast to IProvider<MyElement2> because, I assume, MyElement2 is unrelated to MyElement. But why should I upcast from IProvider<MyElement> to IProvider<IElement>?

Comment: @caerolus, as per your edit: If `T` appears only in output position, the interface can be covariant; it `T` appears only in input position, the interface can be contravariant; but it `T` both in input and output position, the interface can't be variant at all...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque so no easy solution, right? Should I just make MyProvider also implement IProvider<IElement> or work with casts everywhere? This might have to be used by .net 3.5 users, so maybe implementing IProvider<IElement> is better? Thanks!

Comment: @caerolus, no, no easy solution... you could make a non-generic IProvider interface, and also implement it in your class